# Access the pytest PluginManager object inside a runtest hook

Tags: python, pytest

In a pytest plugin, I want to access the configuration inside a `runtest` hook. This works, but feels like a hack. Is there a cleaner way to do it?

```
configuration = None


def pytest_configure(config):
    global configuration
    configuration = config


def pytest_runtest_call(item):
    manager = configuration.pluginmanager
    # Do something with `manager` here.
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always access the config via session object:

```
def pytest_runtest_call(item):
    manager = item.session.config.pluginmanager
```